# Estimate E(Y|X,Z) from E(Y|X) and E[Y|Z]

Tags: regression, conditional-expectation

Can I estimate $E[Y|X, Z]$ if I know $E[Y|X]$ and $E[Y|Z]$?

As an example, let's say I have a model where

$X\sim N(0, 1)$,

$Y = aX+\epsilon_Y, \epsilon_Y \sim N(0, 1)$,

$Z = bY+\epsilon_z, \epsilon_z \sim N(0, 1)$.

What is the expected value of $Y$ given $X, Z$?

Comment: You need to think about the _joint_ distribution of $\varepsilon_Y$ and $\varepsilon_Z$.  The standard approach would be treat these two variables as _independent_, but **you** need to say if that is what you want.

Comment: @DilipSarwate sorry I did not clarify that. Assuming that $\epsilon_Y$ and $\epsilon_z$ are independent, what would be $E[Y|X, Z]$

Comment: @grs: it is incorrect that "Y and Z should be independent given X for $E(Y|X,Z)=E(Y|X)$ to hold". Take e.g.$$Y|X,Z\sim\text{N}(aX,bZ^2)$$

Answer (score 3):

In the Normal-Normal example, assuming independence between $\epsilon_y$ and $\epsilon_Z$
$$Y|X,Z \sim \mathcal{N}(\{aX+bZ\}/\{1+b^2\},1/\{1+b^2\})$$
In the general case, even when $X$ and $Z$ are independent, there is no reason to be able to deduce $\mathbb{E}[Y|X,Z]$ from $\mathbb{E}[Y|X]$ and $\mathbb{E}[Y|Z]$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can you give me a hint on how to get this derivation?

Comment: In your example, it looks like (X,Y,Z) ~ multivariate normal.  So you can use the conditional distribution formula here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions